# How to disable input-prediction and alphabetical input-correction for the Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, prediction

I'm trying to create a text-based game on the Windows phone.

My thought is that mistyping will reduce in-game points and you will be granted higher points
based on the time it takes you to type...

Now to the problem.
Since i am using a textbox for the input and my input scope is text i also get automatic text-correction and input-prediction.

Does anyone know how to disable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, don't use a `Text` `Input Scope` :)

Default `Input Scope` provides no correction and prediction. Does it suitable your needs?

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats exactly what i needed, couldnt find anything on that subject when i googled it! =)

Comment: Not working for WP8.1 ... I can't seem to get the prediction off.